# Nested Radio buttons using mat-radio-group in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, radio-button

I am trying to display nested radio button with an nested json array. But its not working as expected.

```
 <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" formControlName="investmentCategory" fxLayout="column">                                        
                                    <mat-radio-button   *ngFor="let category of investmentCategory" [value]="category.Investment_Category"
                                        [matTooltip]="">{{category.Investment_Category}}                                                                                       
                                            <mat-radio-group *ngIf="showSubCategory " aria-label="Select an option" formControlName="subInvestmentCat" fxLayout="column">                                        
                                                <mat-radio-button  [checked]="false" *ngFor="let subCat of category.Sub_Category" [value]="subCat.Sub_Category"
                                                    [matTooltip]="">{{subCat.Sub_Category}}                                                    
                                                </mat-radio-button>    
                                            </mat-radio-group>                                              
                                    </mat-radio-button>
                                   
                                </mat-radio-group>
```

Output is getting like below.
[image]

Can someone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please state what expected output and desired behavior is in your post.

Comment: When I select first radio button, all the sub options are getting selected and the radio button of parent one is coming to the middle of sub options as shown in the figure.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this problem by placing the sub-group outside the button not inside:

```
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" formControlName="investmentCategory" fxLayout="column">

    <mat-radio-button   *ngFor="let category of investmentCategory" [value]="category.Investment_Category" [matTooltip]="">
        {{category.Investment_Category}}                                                                                       
    </mat-radio-button>

    <mat-radio-group *ngIf="showSubCategory " aria-label="Select an option" formControlName="subInvestmentCat" fxLayout="column">                                        

        <mat-radio-button  [checked]="false" *ngFor="let subCat of category.Sub_Category" [value]="subCat.Sub_Category" [matTooltip]="">
            {{subCat.Sub_Category}}                                                    
        </mat-radio-button>    

    </mat-radio-group>

</mat-radio-group>
```